# How does Postman perform requests

Tags: rest, postman, fetch-api

I was hoping to gain a greater understanding of how Postman works to make it's requests. After using it numerous times to test I have grown extremely curious how it is doing what it does behind the scenes. Is it just JavaScript fetches with a GUI? Is it something more akin to cURL?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

I have Googled quite a bit and the only thing that turns up is how to use it and nothing about how it actually does what it does. I am deeply curious the methodology behind how it is performing it's requests.

Comment: For anyone also curious I have found the answer myself by digging into Postman's repositories. They use their own [HTTP Client](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-request)

Answer (score 2):

Postman uses a variety of technologies to perform requests, including:

JavaScript: Postman's user interface is built on JavaScript, and the requests themselves are also implemented in JavaScript.
Fetch API: Postman uses the Fetch API to make HTTP requests to APIs. The Fetch API is a modern API that provides a consistent way to make HTTP requests in JavaScript.
cURL: Postman can also use cURL to make requests. cURL is a popular command-line tool for making HTTP requests.
When you create a request in Postman, you specify the following information:

The URL of the API endpoint
The HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.)
The request headers
The request body (if any)
Postman then uses the information you specify to create a JavaScript request object. The request object is then passed to the Fetch API or cURL, depending on your preferences.

The Fetch API or cURL then makes the HTTP request to the API endpoint. The response from the API is then returned to Postman, where it is displayed in the Response pane. I hope this helps!